# Samba file sharing on Ubuntu doesn't mask or force permissions for new files

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, file-permissions, samba

I've setup a shared folder on my Ubuntu 10.4 server using Samba and put in the following configuration to the shared folder:

```
[share]
    comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
    path = path..
    browsable = yes
    valid users = @team
    write list = @team
        force group = team
        writable = yes
        printable = no
    guest ok = no
    read only = no
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 0775
    force create mode = 0775
```

My issue is that new files created are still coming up with 644 instead of 664.
Any suggestions on what else to try to ensure that it corrects the permission?

Answer (score 2):

I would try removing the create and directory mask settings. I can get it to work by just using this:

```
force create mode = 0775
force directory mode = 0775
force user = zuallauz
force group = www-data
```

That forces all the new directories and files created to have 0775 permissions.

Failing that you could try setting the parent directory manually once via command line to 775 (or whatever permissions you need) then using:

`inherit permissions = yes`

Theoretically all new files should inherit their parent directory's permissions. Don't forget to restart samba after changing the config:

```
sudo restart smbd
sudo restart nmbd
```

[See good documentation on all the settings here.](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch08.html)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of `create mask` is that samba users are allowed to modify those permissions up to the mask. So if you set it to `0777` for example, then a user would be able to modify all bits. This is *not* the same as unix file masks. So your setting of 0664 would mean that a user can modify the permissions on User (`rw`), Group (`rx`) and Other (`r`). This does *not* mean that the files will be created with those permissions - simply means that the user can *use* those permissions.

You can use `force create mode` instead which *should* do what you need:

```
force create mode = 0664
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i tried using force create mode = 0775 and i still get -rw-r--r-- for files. directories seem to be working correctly: drwxr-xr-x.